# change scss variable with scssphp

Tags: php, sass

I'm using scssphp to see if I can use it to change variables that are set in my existing scss so I've set up a testcase:

```
require_once "scssphp-0.1.7/scss.inc.php";

use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;
use Leafo\ScssPhp\Server;

$scss = new Compiler();
$scss->addImportPath('testsass');

$scss->compile('$color: blue;');
$test = $scss->compile('@import "test.scss"');

echo $test;
```

My test.scss looks like:

```
$color: red;

body {
    background: $color;
}
```

Now I was hoping I could change $color to blue in my php and than compile it and I'm sure the way displayed above is not correct.

But is there a way to change the variable of $color to blue and than recompile my test.scss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this myself with a workaround which works flawlessly.
I've made a config.scss with all my variables in it. And decided to open and rewrite that before compiling my layout.scss which imports config.scss

```
require_once "scssphp-0.1.7/scss.inc.php";

use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;
use Leafo\ScssPhp\Server;

$scss = new Compiler();
$scss->setImportPaths('sass');

//$txt = '$color: yellow;';
$txt = '$font: "Open sans";';
$txt .= '$body-font-size: 15px;';
$txt .= '$containerWidth: 1140px;';
$txt .= '$gutter-size: 15px;';
$txt .= '$primarycolor: red;';
$txt .= '$secondarycolor: blue;';
$txt .= '$background: #e8e3e3;';
$txt .= '$textcolor: $primarycolor;';
$txt .= '$linkcolor: #000;';

$file = fopen('sass/_configuratie.scss', "w");
if (fwrite($file, $txt)) {
    $server = new Server('sass', null, $scss);
    $server->serve();
}
```

Comment: So have you managed to get it work finally with this method? I'm struggling with this for about 2 days.. :(

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm for me. I send a $_POST Request from my javascript to a PHP file as such: layout.php/layout.scss (add the scss file you want to compile to the url). In the same folder I have a `configuratie.scss` which I open with PHP, then rewrite entirely, save it and than I compile the layout.scss which imports the newly written `configuratie.scss`